# How can I set a default variable value before select action in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am completely new to JavaScript, so far i have been able to learn how to get values from my select drop down. However one other thing I would like to do is have a default value which gets displayed when a user visits the page. Then change with the select action. Currently I get no value displayed until after selecting from the drop down. I have tried to search but i have not found any easy to understand guide on how to implement this. See my code below

```js
function val() {
   d = document.getElementById("select_year").value;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
 }
```

```html
<select onchange="val()"  id="select_year">
    <option selected value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome, the default value is exactly what you set it to be ?

Comment: Been trying it in chrome myself. not sure why it didn't work. Seems i was not calling the function with val (); at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you have just to call your function.

```js
function val() {
  d = document.getElementById("select_year").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
}

val();
```

```html
<select onchange="val()" id="select_year">
        <option selected value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
  </select>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Also you can invoke `val` function appending `()` after closing brace

Comment: @DanielBatalla True, but then you will scope this function (anonymous function) and actually I don't know if OP wants it.

Comment: @Kinduser works perfectly, thanks. Is it possible to create a global variable to use in a function that follows. As my intention is not use the value selected in another function, but had to over come that issue first.

Answer (score -1):

Just make a small change.

```
<option selected="selected" value="122"></option>
```

this will be good.

Comment: `<option selected>` and `<option selected="selected">` are the exact same thing. The `selected` attribute doesn't take a value; the option is selected based on the *presence* of this attribute. You could do `selected="false"` to select an option and it would work.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I said, it will always work. You can do `selected="asiudhgsadkasd"` and it will work. Giving the `selected` attribute a value at all is entirely unnecessary. Your answer does not provide a solution to the question that OP is asking because you've essentially just told OP to "add an extra word and everything should work", and i'm telling you that the extra word *does nothing*.

Comment: selected="selected" is required in XHTML